# Joomla component : one view calling multiple models?

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I want a view to call 2 different models for use.

Controller.php

```
class StatsController extends JController {
    function display()
     {
        if( !JRequest::getVar( 'view' ) ) {
            JRequest::setVar('view', 'stats' );
        }
        parent::display();
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Stats** view : (index.php?option=com_stats&view=stats)

```
class StatsViewStats extends JView
{
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $model_helpdesk = & JModel::getInstance('Helpdesk','StatsModel');
    //$model_chart =  & JModel::getInstance('Chart','StatsModel'); 
    //$model_chart =  &$this->getModel('Chart');
    var_dump($model_chart);
    ...
    ...
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

Problem : getting the **Helpdesk model** works fine, but getting the **Chart model** either returns a blanc page , or returns null in **var_dump**. How can i get this second model for use (without modifying the controller) ??

Answer (score 3):

In your controller, you'll need to do the following:

```
$view = &$this->getView('Stats', 'html');
$view->setModel($this->getModel('Stats'), true);
$view->setModel($this->getModel('Chart'));
$view->setModel($this->getModel('Helpdesk'));
$view->display();
```

Then you can access each model using the following:

```
$chartModel = $this->getModel('Chart');
$helpdeskModel = $this->getModel('Helpdesk');
```

[Source](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_multiple_models_in_an_MVC_component)

Comment: Sorry, but i already saw that & it doesn't help !
I just need to keep my controller's display function untouched so i can access the view directly via **index.php?option=com_stats&view=XXXX**

Comment: Where in the controller should this be? In which method?

Comment: OK, I found out. It should be in the display() method in the Controller StatsController (in this case). Thanks :)